# Smarty: How can I pass on the increamenting {counter} value in the {include} function?

Tags: loops, multidimensional-array, include, smarty, counter

This smarty code loops (by calling upon itself with {include}) through a multidimensional array and puts the data per dimension into a multidimensional HTML-list. I would like pass on an incrementing value. So how can pass on the {counter} value in the {include} function?

```
{foreach from=$tree item=wrapper}
    {assign var="idcat" value=$wrapper.idcat}
    {assign var="url" value=$wrapper.item->getLink()}
    {assign var="name" value=$wrapper.item->get('name')}
    {if $idcat|in_array:$path}
        {assign var="aClass" value='active'}
    {else}
        {assign var="aClass" value=''}
    {/if}
    <li>
        <a class="{$aClass|escape}" href="{$url|escape}" title="{$name|escape}">{$name|escape}</a>
    {if $idcat|in_array:$path}
        {include file="navigation_main/template/get.tpl"
            tree=$wrapper.subcats path=$path ulId=""}
    {/if}
    </li>
 {/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The {counter} is global and thus can be used in the sub-template.